# python: TypeError: can't write unicode to binary stream

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following code:

```
file = io.open(tFile,'wb') 
if cData != '':
    file.write('%s\n' % (cData))
```

where cData is a string. The code works fine on Linux and Windows, but fails on all Solaris machines I have with the error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/io.py", line 1045, in write
>       raise TypeError("can't write unicode to binary stream") 
>   TypeError: can't write unicode to binary stream

What's wrong here? thanks

Comment: How is `cData` defined? And, just to make sure, you *are* using the same Python version on all the machines?

Comment: Looks like you are right and it's a python bug existed in py2.6. It appears that all our solaris boxes have Python 2.6 version and all linux and win are 2.7, so I was thinking it's a solaris-platform specific problem. I installed python 2.6 on linux and reproduced it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`io.open` is for interacting with Unicode data. If you want to write byte strings (i.e. Python 2 `str`), use the built-in `open` function instead.

If you really want to use `io.open`, you need to either decode your string (if it is decodable)

```
file.write(('%s\n' % (cData)).decode())
```

or use a Unicode literal

```
file.write(u'%s\n' % (cData))
```

I assume you understand basic string encoding principles here. If `cData` is not ASCII-compatible you'll need to provide appropriate encoding names yourself.

Comment: unicode literal didn't help. cData is ASCII characters in my case.